# ObjC, revert to interface builder autolayout constraints, after adding / removing programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout, ios7.1

I have a free version of my app and I remove + add autolayout constraints (to hide a premium feature), however if the user purchases my app I'd like to revert back to to the constraints set by interface builder.

I'm hoping there's a method which will achieve this, but I haven't been able to find it so far?

Here's what I have

```
if (!purchased) {

[self.tblOtherAccounts addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[tblOtherAccounts(==0)]"
   options:0
   metrics:nil
   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tblOtherAccounts)]];


NSDictionary *views = @{ @"tblOtherAccounts" : self.tblOtherAccounts, 
   @"butBackAllAc" : butBackAllAc  };

[self.view removeConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint 
   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[tblOtherAccounts]-(12)-[butBackAllAc]"
   options:0
   metrics:nil
   views:views]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint 
   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[tblOtherAccounts]-(0)-[butBackAllAc]"
   options:0
   metrics:nil
   views:views]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an IBOutlet to store your constraint in your ViewController :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint;
```

Then update its value :

```
_myConstraint.constant = 100.0f;
[_myView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[_myView layoutIfNeeded];
```

---

Regarding your comment on setting the relation to "equals", I don't think you'll be able to do that.

One thing you can do though is use your storyboard-generated constraint as a placeholder :

```
NSLayoutConstraint *newConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_myConstraint.firstItem
                                                                 attribute:_myConstraint.firstAttribute
                                                                 relatedBy:_myConstraint.relation
                                                                    toItem:_myConstraint.secondItem
                                                                 attribute:_myConstraint.secondAttribute
                                                                multiplier:_myConstraint.multiplier
                                                                  constant:_myConstraint.constant];

[_myConstraint.secondItem removeConstraint:_myConstraint];
[constraint.secondItem addConstraint:newConstraint];
```

Of course the code above will create an exact duplicate of your constraint, but you can edit it to change the appropriate values to fit your needs.

Comment: My bad, you should call the last two methods on the impacted view, I edited my answer.

Comment: I've added some code to my answer, I'm not sure if it's possible to change the relation to equals with an outlet

Comment: @Jules : I added some code regarding constraint editing before you added code to your question. I will check and add more precision to my answer if required.

Comment: thanks again, so It's probably going to easier to keep the load time constraint in a variable and use that afterward if they purchase, otherwise I'm going to loose the height which i'll have overwritten to zero.

Comment: Yes, I think using "placeholder" constraints (last part of my answer) is a good way to go..

Comment: this looked approach had promise, but when removing and adding constraints, where I use copy and add new ones or use vfl, won't satisfy autolayout, not sure  how to proceed.

Comment: I think this is another issue.. You should probably accept an answer here, and open a new question with more information about the new issue you're facing.

Comment: one last question, I think I mis-understood when you said placeholder, do you mean to setup other constraints in interface and them set to remove on build then apply them when required?

Comment: Something like that. Create the right constraints for a paid version in storyboard, link them to your code, and at runtime, create copies and adjust the parameters you need, remove the first ones and add the new ones. In this case, the "placeholders" are the one initially created but removed at runtime.

Comment: This got my on the right track and this helped too http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/restoring-nslayoutconstraints-after-a-change/

Answer (score 0):

I think, you cannot do exactly that.
You need to perform that logic in code. I.e. apply some constraints, then, on user action, apply another set of constraints.

Example:
You have 2 constraints:

```
@property ... topConstraint;
@property ... leadingConstraint;
```

At the start you assign them some values:

```
topConstraint.constant = 100;
leadingConstraint.constant = 100;
```

After some user action, modify them:

```
topConstraint.constant = 150;
leadingConstraint.constant = 150;
```

Comment: thanks for your input, hmmm, I'm wondering if I can assign them to a variable before hand and assign back afterwards, still looking..

Comment: Yep, that's an option.

Comment: There's no method. You just store constraints in the properties and then modify them as needed.