# Obj-C, changing autolayout at runtime, woes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout, ios7.1

I'm trying try hide table view and move a button up the screen, which is different to my autolayout setup. Basically, I have a free version of my app where I hide things, then if they purchase I need to set the constraints back to those in interface builder.

I have a similar question open, but I think I'm fundamentally flawed in my approach.... (I've taken the advice of something who provided and answer, asking this separate question).

[ObjC, revert to interface builder autolayout constraints, after adding / removing programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433439/objc-revert-to-interface-builder-autolayout-constraints-after-adding-removin)

I can move things up fine, which modifies my interface builder constraints.
But, when the user clicks upgrade, I cannot then set the modify they again / constraints back.

No matter what I do, use visual format language at runtime, or use `NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem` outlets to copy and then modify my constraints it doesn't change. I've tried removing constraint outlets, copying those I stored at viewdidload and remove vfl constraints, exact copies of those which I added for my free version.

I was getting some vfl warnings, until I added priorities.

Is there somewhat I can dump out the vfl for everything and try and figure out the problem or can something suggest the why the approaches I have tried have failed?

Comment: Do you call layoutIfNeeded after modifying your constraints?

Comment: Have you taken the advice on your previous question? I.e., are you simply changing the `constant` values on existing constraints rather than replacing and restoring or recreating constraints? It seems like a simple layout which should only require changing the `constant` values for your interface builder constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attempting to replace and restore constraints at runtime, consider setting up all the constraints you will need in Interface Builder, with references to those which are state-dependent. Then, when state changes according to your own logic, activate the state-appropriate constraint(s) and deactivate the inappropriate ones. `NSLayoutConstraint` has an `active` property, which determines whether it is used for laying out its view.

Comment: OK, if I move to another view using my tab bar and back, it updates, so I just need to update my view, any suggestions?

Comment: This got me 90% of the way to solving my problem, however this was also a great help http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/restoring-nslayoutconstraints-after-a-change/